# os.execv returns OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to have a Python script automatically download an updated version of itself, replace the existing version, then restart automatically so that it loads the new version.

I'm currently using the following code to restart it:

```
os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
```

However, this isn't working. Whenever Python tries to run this line, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "N:\CardDB\Station\Read.py", line 195, in <module>
    else:
File "N:\CardDB\Station\Read.py", line 187, in run_update
    print("\n\nWould you like to install this update?")
File "N:\CardDB\Station\Read.py", line 144, in update
    f.write(version)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Other questions on StackOverflow suggest that it's due to a missing shebang line, but I've made sure that it isn't missing - the first line of my script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike unix OSes, Windows does not seem to have native support for interpreted executables. `os.execv` requires a binary and fails because it is given a text file. So instead of calling the script directly, call the python interpreter

```
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable, __file__] + sys.argv)
```

On, e.g., Linux, you can use `os.execv(__file__, [__file__] + sys.argv)` if the script is marked executable and contains a shebang line. For nonexecutable scripts you have to call the python executable as above.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me - It's no longer throwing an error, but instead is just opening the Python interpreter without running the script.

Comment: @oolivero45 I've fixed the call to `execv`. You have to pass a name for the program as `argv[0]`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it - It doesn't work when it's run from IDLE, but that doesn't matter - it won't need to be run that way anyway. It works perfectly when run directly from the .py file.